# How to create a box with a curved side with gradient wpf

Tags: wpf, xaml, staticresource

I'm wanting to create a background style in xaml, that is similar to the image below, how could I do this?

[image]

Comment: ImageBrush would work if you just used that image.

Comment: thanks @IntStarFoo, I realize to do this via an image is probably easier, but I would rather it be through a resource style if this is possible.

Comment: Style the control that has the background you want to change.  In the control template, add a `Path` with the above shape that is filled with a `LinearGradientBrush`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the object you want to put this background on is a border or a grid, you can just add a `Path` object behind the rest of your content in that control:

```
<Border Width="100" Height="50">
  <Path Data="m0,0 L 0 50 L 100 50 L 100 30 C 70 0 30 25 0 0">
    <Path.Fill>
      <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.5,0" EndPoint="0.5,1">
        <GradientStop Offset="0.3" Color="Green"/>
        <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="#FF99bb99"/>
      </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Path.Fill>
  </Path>
</Border>
```